# λ vector on Tensor CP Decomposition with Alternating Least Square

Tags: tensor, decomposition, als

I am trying to understand the procedure of tensor cp decomposition with alternating least squares based on [this](https://www.kolda.net/publication/TensorReview.pdf) paper.
At page 464 is referred that *"It is often useful to assume that the columns of A, B, and C are normalized to length one with the weights absorbed into the vector λ "*
In addition, at page 471 line 7 of psedo code is "

```
normalize columns of A(n) (storing norms as λ)
```

"

I don't understand what values will be stored on vector λ and on matrix Λ.

What i understand is that we do normalization to ever column of the factor matrices and we store norms on a new vector λ
For example for a 3x3x3 tensor with rank=3, will have three 3x3 factors A,B and C and after normalize to unit length every column of all these matrices, i will end up with 9 norms. These norms will be the values of the diagonal matrix Λ ?

Am i missing something?
Thank you

Tensor CP Decomposition with Alternating Least Square.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the paper, but it looks like this is probably what they mean:

Suppose we're looking at the 3x3 case, since that's easy to draw. We have
fixed, non-normalized matrices $A,B,C$ and want matrices $a_r, b_r, c_r$ that are column normalized, and some matrix $\lambda$ s.t. $A B C = \lambda a_r b_r c_r$

```
\lambda A = 
/ a1 b1 c1 \  / x1 x2 x1 \     / a1 x1 + b1 y1 + c1 z1; a1 x2 + b1 y2 + c1 z2;  ... \
| a2 b2 c2 |  | y1 y2 y2 |  =  | a2 x1 + b2 y1 + c2 z1; ...                         |
\ a3 b3 c3 /  \ z1 z2 z3 /     \ a3 x1 + b3 y1 + c3 z1; ...                         /
```

Then solve the following system of linear equations for $(a b c)$ to enforce the column-normalization of $\lambda A$:

```
/1\    / (a1+a2+a3) x1 + (b1+b2+b3) y1 + (c1+c2+c3) z1 \
|1| =  | (a1+a2+a3) x2 + (b1+b2+b3) y2 + (c1+c2+c3) z2 |
\1/    \ (a1+a2+a3) x3 + (b1+b2+b3) z2 + (c1+c2+c3) z3 /
```

We've technically got too many free variables here, but since we only care about the sum of, e.g., $a1+a2+a3$, and not
what any individual a is, we'll just enforce the constraint that $\lambda$ be a diagonal matrix, at which point we have:

```
/1\    / a1 x1 + b2 y1 + c3 z1 \
|1| =  | a1 x2 + b2 y2 + c3 z2 |
\1/    \ a1 x3 + b2 z2 + c3 z3 /
```

We plug that into a linear equation solver to get values for $a1,b2,c3$.  We then do the same thing for B and C and multiply all the lambdas together (taking advantage of the associativity of matrix multiplication to pull them all to the left),
at which point $A B C = \lambda a_r b_r c_r$, and all the $foo_r$ matrices have normalized columns.